# Strictly one attribute item inside fieldarray must be true

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am implementing a dynamic form with Yup and Formik. I have a `FieldArray` with elements that I can add and remove. Each time I add it, it adds a row with an object having a first name, last name and a boolean if it is the default person.

How to check that strictly one person in the list is the default person?

```js
export const schemaPerson = () => {
  return Yup.object()
    .shape({
      persons: Yup.array()
        .of(
          Yup.object().shape({
            firstname: Yup.string()
              .required(),
            lastname: Yup.string()
              .required(),
            isDefault: Yup.boolean()
              .required()
          })),
    }).min(1, 'At least one person is required');
};
```

Comment: filtering the array? I am guessing is one of the formik states. So get that state and filter the array. Is that what you want?

Comment: What I would like is that Yup displays an error if the user creates more than one person as a default person or on the contrary, no person in the list is default. There must be strictly one person with the checkbox checked.